# Segmentation fault right at the end of the program

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with this code.
It works as expected, excepting that it gets Seg fault right at the end.

Here is the code:

```
void distribuie(int *nrP, pach *pachet, post *postas) { 

    int nrPos, k, i, j;
    nrPos = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < 18; k++)
        pos[k].nrPac = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < *nrP; i++) {
        int distributed = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < nrPos; j++) 
            if (pac[i].idCar == pos[j].id) {
                pos[j].vec[pos[j].nrPac] = pac[i].id;
                pos[j].nrPac++;
                distributed = 1;
                break;
            }
        if (distributed == 0) {
            pos[nrPos].id = pac[i].idCar;
            pos[nrPos].vec[0] = pac[i].id;
            pos[nrPos].nrPac = 1;
            nrPos++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nrPos; i++) {
        printf("%d %d ", pos[i].id, pos[i].nrPac);
        for (j = 0; j < pos[i].nrPac; j++)
            printf("%d ", pos[i].vec[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

and calling this function in main().

Running with gdb resulted in this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000001 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Did you do a backtrace on that `gdb` session?

Comment: Try running valgrind  on it... you probably mess with the memory somewhere
Also, why is nrP a pointer to int if you never change its value ?

Comment: @Antzi Running with valgrind shows the same:
 Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

==15484==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0

==15484==    at 0x1: ???

HEAP SUMMARY:

==15484==     in use at exit: 390 bytes in 10 blocks

==15484==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 0 frees, 390 bytes 
allocated

==15484== 

==15484== LEAK SUMMARY:

==15484==    definitely lost: 390 bytes in 10 blocks

Comment: is 'pos' some kind of global array or is it a typo?

Comment: @WhozCraig (gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000001 in ?? ()
I have no idea what to do next

Comment: @CyberSpock Yes it is a global array.

Comment: as is also apparently pac. Without a reproducible case, there isn't much we can do besides suggest the obvious, you're blasting over your stack and `main()` is `ret` ing to garbage. Its going to take more than just running it in a debugger, I'm afraid.

Comment: Another suggestion is to add asserts in your function making sure that all indices are inside expected sizes. e.g. `assert( sizeof( pos ) / sizeof( pos[0] ) >= 18 );`

Answer (score 1):

If `gdb` can't find the stack trace, it means your code wrote over the stack so thoroughly that neither the normal C runtime nor `gdb` can find the information about where the function should return on the stack.

Or, in other words, you have a (major) stack overflow.

Somewhere, your code is writing out of bounds of an array.  It is curious that the code posted references global variables `pos` and `pac` but is passed (unused) variables `postas` and `pachet`.  It suggests that the code you're showing isn't the code you're executing.  However, assuming that `pos` and `pac` are really spelled the same as `postas` and `pachet`, then it could be that you are mishandling the call to your `distribuie()` function.  (If, as a comment suggests, `pos` and `pac` really are global variables, then why does the function get passed `postas` and `pachet`?)

Are you getting any compilation warnings?  Have you enabled compilation warnings?  If you've got GCC, does the code compile cleanly with `-Wall`?  What about with `-Wall -Wextra`?  If you're getting any warnings, fix the causes.  Remember, at this stage in your career, it is probable that the C compiler knows more about C than you do.

You can help yourself with the debugging by printing key values (like `*nrP`) on entry to the function.  If that isn't a sane value, you know where to start looking.  You might also take a good look at the data for the line:

```
pos[j].vec[pos[j].nrPac] = pac[i].id;
```

There is lots of room there for things to go badly astray!

Answer (score 1):

I lack information to completely help you: I don't know the size of the pos[] array. The loop with k<18 suggests it is 18 elements (but it could be less; I simply don't know). Then you start processing *nrP pachets, but you don't check that you process at most 18 of these. If there are more, you overwrite some other memory. Then you want to print the result et voila, a segmentation fault, meaning some memory got corrupted, is used by someone thinking it is a valid pionter, but the pointer is invalid and...bang - segfault.

So the for loop should at least check the bounds (assuming 18):

```
for (i = 0; i < *nrP && i < 18; i++) {
```

In the same way, the pos structure apparently has an array of vec, but its size is unknown and by the same reasoning can be 18, can be less or an be more:

```
pos[j].vec[pos[j].nrPac]
```

If you add all your bounds checks it will probably run.

Comment: The pos array has a max size of 32. By the way, if I loop the k to 32, it sometimes goes Seg fault when reaching k = 19 but not always.. why is that?

Comment: Has a "max size of 32" (but could be smaller) or "has a size of 32"? The reason of a seg foult not always is that the memory is corrupt, and that can be in a different every time the program is run. Such behaviour is typical of memory corruption.